# Button no longer does what it is supposed to do

Tags: android, button, onclicklistener

I have a button that is meant to swap from one activity to another which use to work but ever since i added the coding for another button to call for zxing's scanning feature the button no longer does anything at all.
This is my MainActivity.java for those who are willing to help

```
 package com.example.mdpmk1;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
    import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button button;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {

        final Context context = this;


        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);


        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if(v.getId()==R.id.scan){
                //scan

                    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(MainActivity.this);
                    integrator.initiateScan();
                }


            }

        });

    }


    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
    {
        //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

            }
        }
    }





    Button button2;

    public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton1() {

        final Context context = this;


        button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getResults);


        button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(context, ScanResult.class);
                startActivity(intent);



            }

        });

    }


    }
```

The button that isn't responding is button2 so if you can help me with anything that would be lovely, Thanks in advance. All help is appreciated.

Comment: Where is `addListenerOnButton1()` called?

Comment: you have set the same layout in both activities `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`

Comment: `addListenerOnButton()`; this name change to `addListenerOnButton1()`;

Comment: You're calling `addListenerOnButton()`, where you should be calling `addListenerOnButton1()`.

Comment: @Raghunandan Was i not suppose to do this? It worked before when the first button use to take you to an alternate screen aswell

Comment: @Aniruddha So i changed the `addListenerOnButton()` to `addListenerOnButton1()` for button2 and yet it still doesn't load up the alternate activity.

Comment: @Sparky to which class button2 belongs to? Please post the full code then it will be easy for all to answer.

Comment: @Aniruddha This belongs to `MainActivity` And this is the full code for MainActivity.java

Comment: @Sparky check my answer and let me know if it helps. Change context to MainActivity.this in intent.

Answer (score 0):

For both buttons You are adding Same Listener

> addListenerOnButton();
>
> addListenerOnButton1();

please change in button2 accordingly

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
Button bt, bt2;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);
                bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getResults);



                bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                         // do initiatescan
                    }
                });

                bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {

                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanResult.class);
                        startActivity(intent);



                    }

                });



            }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
                {
                    //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
                    if (requestCode == 0) {
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

                        }
                    }
                }


            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

        }
```

**Edit**:Change your onCreate method with this one and check. Hope it works.

Comment: By no information provided along with this i assume you want me to replace my whole code with this?

Comment: My application now crashes upon clicking button one and button 2 still doesnt take me to another page

Comment: Check the button ids and on which line it showing error?

Comment: I did all the button ids, Where would i find what line is causing the crash (There are no errors that i can see in the code)

Comment: Please create one more thread of question and post all your codes there. And give me the link here. Does your app force closes? Debug and you will come to know where the error is or check your logcat.

Comment: Didn't notice your change to the code and only got the first version before your second edit, Code doesn't crash with first button anymore, Second button still doesn't change pages, What files of code do you want me to post?

Comment: Application crashes on click of second button?. Share IntentIntegrator class. If your application crashes on click of second button then check whether you have declared `ScanResult` in `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: I think you have the buttons the wrong way round, The first button crashed on click until you edited the code, The first button is to call upon the scan which after your edit works like it did before which is without a flaw, The second button which is to start an intent to swap to the second screen does nothing upon clicking it, This is my original problem and hasn't changed since everyone started giving advise on what to do, The rest of the code still works fine, the only thing that doesn't work is that the second button doesn't do anything when clicked.

Comment: Can you post your entire project? Try to debug what is happening on click of button2. Just do one thing, create a new thread of question and post entire code. Surely you will get help.

Comment: So how do i post my entire project at once? Posting the code for each one would take up alot of un-necessary room i would think

Comment: Just post your MainActivity code, IntentIntegrator code and xml file. It won't take up much space and time. Just copy and paste.

Comment: Just post your MainActivity code, IntentIntegrator code and xml file. It won't take up much space and time. Just copy and paste. What is `ScanResult`? Is it extending `Activity` or `BroadCastReceiver`?

Comment: [Here you are](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671817/button-not-doing-anything-when-it-should)