# Button not doing anything when it should

Tags: java, android, request

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mdpmk1;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.wifi.ScanResult;
import android.widget.Button;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentIntegrator;
import com.google.zxing.integration.android.IntentResult;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 Button bt, bt2;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.scan);
     bt2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.getResults);



     bt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              // do initiatescan
         }
     });

     bt2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {

             Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanResult.class);
             startActivity(intent);



         }

     });



 }

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) 
     {
         //super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
         if (requestCode == 0) {
             if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

             } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {

             }
         }
     }


 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
     getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
     return true;
 }

}
```

IntentIntegrator.java
Can be found [HERE](https://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android-integration/src/com/google/zxing/integration/android/IntentResult.java?r=2260)

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/appName"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/scan"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/scanClick" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/getResults"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/getResults" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Mainfest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.mdpmk1"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:debuggable="true"
        android:name="com.example.mdpmk1.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ScanScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".ScanResults" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

This is in response to Aniruddha who requested this code to help me with question asked [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23669615/button-no-longer-does-what-its-suppose-to/23670577?) If anyone else could tell me why my button 2 doesnt work that would be lovely thanks.

Comment: it should work navigate to second activity

Comment: But that is my problem, When on the application and i click the second button it doesn't navigate to the second page, I'm really frustrated by this

Comment: the code seems ok. post the manifest fine

Comment: Edited the main post to include it

Comment: @Sparky does it crash??

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, does it throw an exception? Or is it just that nothing happens?

Comment: @Raghunandan It doesn't crash it just sits there like i have done nothing, I can click the other button and it still works fine even after i click button 2

Comment: @Sparky it should `ScanResults` and `ScanResult` are not the same

Comment: @Raghunandan nice job. The manifest and the intent don't have the same spelling for ScanResult(s). You should post it as an answer I think.

Comment: @Sparky change the `ScanResults` in Manifest to `ScanResult`

Comment: @Raghunandan I dont know when this changed but that was the problem, Im amazed that it didnt give me an error in the code because of that, Thankyou got the fix been trying to get that figured out for about 3h so far....

Comment: @Sparky you should get a expcetion check the stactrace. check my post

Comment: Did you defined your class ScanResult in the manifest file??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have

```
<activity android:name=".ScanResults" />
```

And when using intent

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ScanResult.class);
```

`ScanResults` and `ScanResult` are not the same.

If Activity is not found you should get `ActivityNotFoundException`.

> This exception is thrown when a call to startActivity(Intent) or one
>   of its variants fails because an Activity can not be found to execute
>   the given Intent.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ActivityNotFoundException.html

Comment: Unfortunately i was not getting this error in my code which was the start of my problem, I must of change it some time without noticing. Thanks